# How can i use spring security to authenticate users with an Id and password instead of username and password

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am new to spring security and want to authenticate users having a userId and password.
The userId is given to users upon registration.

And the second problem is the userId and password are in different tables.
So, how can I customize spring security to meet both requirements.

Here is my security config class.
I am using spring boot 2

> public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

```
@Autowired
private DbConfig dbConfig;

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring()
        .antMatchers("/static/**")
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/public/**")
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/index.html");
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    auth.jdbcAuthentication()
        .dataSource(dbConfig.dataSource())
        .usersByUsernameQuery("select username,password,active from user where username=?")
        .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select username,authority from authorities where username=?")
        .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}

 private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {

    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Override
 protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
     http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/login")
        .permitAll()
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login")
        .defaultSuccessUrl("/dashboard")
        .and()
        .csrf()
        .disable();
 }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use your own [`UserDetailsService`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#tech-userdetailsservice):

```java
public MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Override
    public User loadUserByUsername(String username) {
        // write the query yourself
    }
}
```

And then in your configuration:

```java
@Bean
@Override
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    return new MyUserDetailsService();
}
```

You can find more details in [the section of the Spring Security Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#jc-authentication-userdetailsservice) dedicated to your question.